# How to Add a PHP Property to a SimpleXMLElement?

Tags: php, oop, simplexml

I have a subclass of a `SimpleXMLElement` that I want to a class properties to that will define some default values for an attribute of created child-nodes.

In order to set this values, I attempted to override `addChild` with the following method:

```
public function addChild($name, $value = '')
{
    $child = parent::addChild($name, $enc_val);
    error_log(print_r($this->default_link_type, true));
    $child->set_default_val($this->default_val);
    return $child;
}
```

**The problem is the expression: `$this->default_val` doesn't return the value of the property, but instead creates a new empty child object and returns it.**

Can anyone think of a way of overriding this behvior for certain properties? Or think of any hack that will allow me to have essentially a global state for all of these `SimpleXMLElement` subclasses that doesn't involve writing to a file, key-value store etc.?

Comment: All you want to do is add child nodes via SimpleXMLElement with some default attribute values upon creation? Take a look at [SimpleXMLElement::addAttribute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addattribute.php), it should be as simple as `$child->addAttribute('attribute-name', $this->default_val);`. Regarding the problem you state, without seeing your subclass definition and what `set_default_val` and `$this->default_val` are it won't be easy to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The below doesn't fully work because now when do call `asXML()` all the elements have the config property as a child node. So I'm still after a solution.

I have finally found the answer by experimenting with various classes/methods in PHP's [Reflection API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php).

You can add this to the SimpleXMLElement sublass to a get the value of a property of the current object:

```
protected function get_property($name)
{
    $rc = new ReflectionClass($this);
    $props = $rc->getDefaultProperties();
    if (!isset($props[$name])) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(
            '$name does not hold the value of a valid property!'
        );
    }
    return $props[$name];
}
```

Using methods such as ReflectionClass::getProperty() *will not work*.